# C++ getline(string) segmentation fault with regards to multithreading

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, shell, fork

I apologize for the somewhat ambiguous title but I really couldn't think of a nicer way to write it.

I'm designing a shell for a class that is supposed to be able to handle backgrounding. However, because the shell doesn't wait for the child process when backgrounding is enabled, I thought it would be best to create a second thread whose sole purpose is to clean up the child process when it's finished. Now this works fine until the child process ends. When the child process ends, the next input I enter gives me a segmentation fault. Using gdb, I've figured out that the fault is coming from within my getline function.

I've tested it and std::cin doesn't seem to be the problem. Also, when not backgrounding, the whole thing works fine, no problems whatsoever.

To test backgrounding, I wrote a program a.out that prints, sleeps for ten seconds, then prints again before exiting.
The output:

```
/Users/opname/Shell Project>./a.out&
/Users/opname/Shell Project>Sleep time!
ls
opshell   a.out     pseudocode.c    test.txt
opshell.cpp a.out.dSYM  shell.h     test2.txt
opshell.dSYM    gcctest.c   sleeper.c   testdir
/Users/opname/Shell Project>Awake time!
ls
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Here's the code where I fork the process and create the new thread:

```
            pid_t cpid = fork();
            if (cpid > 0) {
                int status;
                if (conc) { // if backgrounding enabled
                    pthread_t waiter;
                    struct tcpara *pm = (struct tcpara*) malloc(sizeof(struct tcpara));
                    pm->cpid = cpid;
                    pm->status = &status;
                    pthread_create(&waiter, NULL, &thread_handler, (void*)pm);
                    pthread_detach(waiter);
                }
                else waitpid(cpid, &status, 0);
                break;

            } else if (cpid == 0) {
                loc += cmd;
                execv(loc.c_str(), argv);
                _exit(0);
            }
```

And here's the subroutine called by the waiter thread:

```
void *thread_handler(void *pm) {
  struct tcpara *ofpm = (struct tcpara*) pm;
  waitpid(ofpm->cpid, ofpm->status, 0);
  free(pm);
  return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try allocating the status variable dynamically. When the thread must use it, it doesn't exist anymore because it went out of scope.
I think it happens the same with `waiter`.
You can try make them static.

Comment: Shame on me. Thanks a lot bud.